# How to seal a water tap

Tags: leak

This old water tap leaks a lot, at the area pointed at by the little red arrow.

It does not leak from the spout, but from where the lever enters the housing (sorry, I'm not native english, I hope I'm using the words correctly...).

[image]

It leaks only when turned on; when the water is off, it is completely dry. In the past, this did not matter to me, but I would like to use an automatic system with it now, which means that it will be open all the time.

So what do I do? I guess I unscrew the nut where the arrow points, and will then be able to take out the assembly, clean it up etc., but then what? Is it enough to wrap it in hemp and screw it in again?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to just snug up the packing nut half a turn and be done with it. Otherwise take the old packing washer to your local hardware store and find a replacement.

Comment: Totally agree: take the washer to your local hardware and replace it, your tap will last another qarter-century before need to replace the washer again.

Comment: Alright. It will be interesting to see whether I can move the nut at all. Before that, I need to close the valve in front of it, and *that* also does not move. ;) I assume it (the valve in the cellar) has last been opened/closed decades ago, judging from the gunk